# Replacement variable inside of the replacing variable

Tags: php, function, variables, global-variables, anonymous-function

I have a function, that check user language and write it down in a variable. After a time, i come of idea to merge they, so that i need a call the function anytime before the first use of a variable, so i put a call of function inside of var, with a idea, that i would be replace it self. But it does not working, becouse it trying to give me a "Closure Object" back, i think it is a function in clear and not the result :( Here is the important part of code:

```
$GLOBALS['user_language'] = function()
{
    return get_user_language();
}

function get_user_language()
{
    $user_language = 'en';
    $GLOBALS['user_language'] = $user_language;
    return $user_language;
}

//somewhere in the script
print_r($GLOBALS['user_language']);
```

I wish to get `'en'` out, nothing more.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense.  Your description of what you want to do is not very descriptive either.  You can't call a function from a variable.   Why don't you just paste your whole script instead of trying to sugar coat a fake version of it that doesn't make any sense?

Comment: What do you need more, if the error is here? For what do you need 200 lines of code more, to know how I set the `$user_language` variable? It is not the point of question.

Comment: @Dmi7ry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style

Comment: @BASILIO, Whitesmiths_style is ok, but TABS need changing to space - TABS are not displayed correctly

Comment: @Dmi7ry can you make screenshot of the not correctly displaying of tabs? I use Opera under Debian and do not see any problems in it :O

Comment: @BASILIO http://rghost.ru/46666636/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_user_language()
{
    $user_language = 'en';
    $GLOBALS['user_language'] = $user_language;
    return $user_language;
}

$GLOBALS['user_language'] = get_user_language();


//somewhere in the script
print_r($GLOBALS['user_language']);
```

But this is strange because you set it already in `get_user_language()` then you pull it again.  It would almost create a loop.  The proper way would probably be to remove the `$GLOBALS['user_language'] = $user_language;` from the function.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Run it and you would be understanding me, why i do so ;) http://pastebin.com/mNVPk4pi

Comment: Damn, I was too early for dance from happy end. It is not, what i want. I need a call of `get_user_language()` ONLY i i call `$GLOBALS['user_language']` and your example do it any time the script runs

Answer (score 0):

Just use `print_r(get_user_language())` instead of `print_r($GLOBALS['user_language']);`.

If getting the user's language multiple times would be particularly slow (*e.g.* a database query would be executed over and over again), you can do something like this:

```
function get_user_language()
{
    static $user_language = null;
    if ($user_language === null) {
        $user_language = 'en'; // this would be where you make the DB query
    }
    return $user_language;
}
```

In practice, in a large PHP application, this code would generally be located in a [class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and would store the value as an object property, so that, for example, the application can cache DB query results for multiple users rather than for only the current one.

Comment: "Just use print_r(get_user_language())" This is what i wish to avoid. When I forgot anywhere to put it at the start, i spend a lot of time, to search for the error. I wish make it autonomous

Comment: @BASILIO: Is replacing all occurrences of `$user_language` with `get_user_language()` really not an option? PHP does have a "magic getter" feature for objects, but not for global variables.